# How find template from array?

Tags: c#, templates

How find template in array ? 
Template

```
int[] = {X, X, X}; //(example 3,3,3)
```

, or template

```
int[,] temp2 = 
{
    {X, X, ?}
    {?, X, X}
}
```

Example

```
int[,] temp2 = 
{
    {3, 3, 1}
    {2, 3, 3}
}
```

For example, in such an array?

```
int[,] a = new int[,]
{
    { 1, 4, 5, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 1, 3 },
    { 1, 1, 2, 4, 4 },
    { 4, 4, 3, 3, 3 },
    { 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 }
};
```

Is there a faster way than searching each cell and its neighboring cells?

Comment: Unclear question, please review and rephrase requirements.

Comment: Are you basically trying to find one bitmap inside another bitmap?

Comment: *Is there a faster way than searching each cell and its neighboring cells?* Probably there isn't. The only thing you can do is knowing that if your template is 3xcolumns, in a 5 columns data set it can start only on columns 0, 1 or 2

Comment: @Smit I'll say that the question is: given `temp2`, composed of `X` and "whatever (`?`)", how can I find the starting row/column of that "pattern" inside the last `a`? (I'll say that the only location where it happens is `(r, c)->(4, 0)`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for patterns inside a bigger array, probably checking cell by cell is the only way to do it. You could do some complex optimizations for skipping the `?` values and speedup a little, but I don't think it would easily work.

A sample code that should do what you asked:

```
// null means anything is ok, X is 0, Y is 1, Z is 2...
int?[,] temp = new int?[,]
{
    {0, 0, null},
    {null, 0, 0}
};

int[,] a = new int[,]
{
    { 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3 },
    { 0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 }
};

int row, col;
bool success = CheckPattern(temp, a, out row, out col);

Console.WriteLine("Success: {0}, row: {1}, col: {2}", success, row, col);
```

and then

```
private static bool CheckPattern(int?[,] temp, int[,] data, out int row, out int col)
{
    int rowsT = temp.GetLength(0);
    int colsT = temp.GetLength(1);

    int rowsD = data.GetLength(0);
    int colsD = data.GetLength(1);

    // Find the "maximum" value of the template (how many different
    // condition are there... If there is only "X" then 1, "X", "Y" then 2,
    // "X", "Y", "Z" then 3...
    int max = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rowsT; j++)
        {
            if (temp[i, j] != null)
            {
                max = Math.Max(temp[i, j].Value, max);
            }
        }
    }

    // We save in an array the "current" values of "X", "Y", "Z", ...
    int?[] values = new int?[max + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsD - rowsT + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colsD - colsT + 1; j++)
        {
            Array.Clear(values, 0, values.Length);

            bool success = true;

            // Check the template
            for (int k = 0; k < rowsT; k++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < colsT; r++)
                {
                    if (temp[k, r] != null)
                    {
                        int? curr = values[temp[k, r].Value];

                        if (curr == null)
                        {
                            // If this is the first time we check this
                            // condition, then any value is good
                            values[temp[k, r].Value] = data[i + k, j + r];
                        }
                        else if (curr.Value == data[i + k, j + r])
                        {
                            // For subsequent instances we check this
                            // condition, then the data must have the
                            // value found in the previous instance
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            success = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!success)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (success)
            {
                row = i;
                col = j;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    row = 0;
    col = 0;
    return false;
}
```

This piece of code should work even for multiple conditions `"X", "Y"...`